# Gambler's ruin problem with fair coin and unequal bet

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recurrence-relations, markov-chains, gambling

The problem asks for: Let $N > i$. Starting with $i$ dollars, each time a fair coin is tossed if heads, then the gambler wins $2$ dollars and loses $1$ otherwise. What is the probability $P_i$ that the gamblers starting from $i$ goes broke before reaching $N$ dollars.

The question can be turned into a third order linear recurrence equation:
$$
0 = \frac12 P_{n+2} - P_n + \frac12 P_{n-1}
$$
with conditions $P_0 = 1$, $P_N = 0$.
The characteristic equation  is
$$
0 = r^3 - 2r + 1
$$
which has three roots
$$
1, \frac{- 1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{- 1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$
Thus the general solution is
$$
P_i = A + B (\frac{- 1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})^i + C (\frac{- 1 - \sqrt{5}}{2})^i
$$
for some $A, B, C$. The first boundary condition forces $A + B + C =1$. I am not sure how to deduce the coefficients when I have only one boundary condition left... any explanation is appreciated. thank you

Comment: One good method in cases of finding coefficients for reccurence relations with probabilities is that $P_i$ must always be between $0$ and $1$. This generally lets you set some coefficients to $0$ because they would cause the function to grow unboundedly. e.g. in this case $C=0$

Comment: that's a good point thank u!

Comment: Actually thinking about it in this particular case you technically can't conclude $C=0$ using this method because $i$ is bounded. However we can conclude that $C$ is 'small' and that as $N$ tends to infinity $C$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Could you please explain what particular case you are considering to get $C = 0$? I seem to be getting $B = C = 0$ if $N$ is large enough, which seems to imply that $P_i = 1$ if $N$ is very big....

Comment: If for now we ignore the problem that $N$ is supposed to be bounded then the idea is to observe that $|\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}|<1$ and $|\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}|>1$ so for any non-zero choice of $C$, $P_i$ will have absolute value greater than $1$ for sufficiently large $i$ (Note that $B$ is not affected in the same way as it eventually becomes essentially 0). However in your case we can't use this as $i$ is bounded. I believe that the correct replacement is simply the boundary condition at $N$. Unfortunately that means that my suggestion won't help here

Comment: I think the correct way to get an additional boundary condition is to look at $P_{N-1}$. We have $P_{N-1}=\frac{1}{2}P_{N-2}$. Substituting $P_n=A+B\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}^n+C\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}^n$ gives us new conditions required to be satisfied. The reason these are new conditions is that you haven't declared that $P_{N+1}=0$ so when we add $2$ to $N-1$ we fall outside the defined range. The set of equations you get from this aren't nice but in principle can be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process can end at three values: $0,N$ and $N+1$. Thus there are three relevant boundary values: $P_0=1$ and $P_N=P_{N+1}=0$.

One can avoid solving equations as follows.
Write $x_n:=P_n-P_{n+1}$ for $n=0,1,\dots,N$. Then
for $1 \le n \le N-1$, we have
$$P_n=(P_{n-1}+P_{n+2})/2 =(P_n+x_{n-1}+P_n-x_n-x_{n+1})/2 \,,$$
so  $x_{n-1}=x_n+x_{n+1}$.
Thus $y_k=x_{N-k}$ satisfy the Fibonacci recurrence
$$y_{k+1}=y_k+y_{k-1} \quad \text{for} \quad k=1,\dots, N-1 \,.$$
Since $y_0=0$, we infer that
$y_k=y_1 F_k$ for $k=0,\dots, N$, where $F_0=0, F_1=1, F_2=1,\dots$ is the   Fibonacci sequence.
Recall that $$ F_1+\dots +F_k=F_{k+2}-1 \,,$$
which can be easily verified inductively.
Therefore, for $m \in [0,N]$ we have
$$P_m=P_N+ y_1+\dots +y_{N-m} = y_1 (F_{N-m+2}-1) \,.$$
Taking $m=0$ yields $1=y_1(F_{N+2}-1)$, so we conclude that
$$\forall m \in [0,N], \quad P_m=\frac{F_{N-m+2}-1}{F_{N+2}-1} \,.$$